# What is the most appropriate statistical test for finding differences in techniques submitted to a computer vision challenge?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, computer-vision

I am designing a typical computer vision segmentation challenge in which there are thousands of images and reference segmentation pairs in a training set, and thousands of images in a test set. There are multiple different training and test sets. Participants can use the training set to fit a segmentation technique, and submit their predicted segmentations on the test set.

On each image I calculate different metrics, but for the purpose of this question let's just focus on the [Dice metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) which is very popular in segmentation challenges. For each submitted segmentation method and for each image in the test set, I calculate the Dice metric. This gives me a set of Dice scores per submission. I can calculate and report aggregate measures such as the mean and median Dice score for each method, but I want to find the statistical differences between submitted methods.

I think some sort of ANOVA is the most appropriate, because I want to make multiple comparisons between all the submitted techniques. However I am not sure about one-way, *n*-way, and whether a repeated measures model is needed? In my mind the different independent factors are: segmentation method, image ID, test set. The dependent variable is the Dice score. The reason I feel a repeated measured model might be appropriate is because each image in a test set is segmented by the different methods submitted by participants - but I am not sure if this is the intended use-case for a RMM. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you have a Dice per image, you can do a non-parametric test among the Dices of the test images across the techniques. Kruskal-Wallis is a good option. To perform multiple comparisons you may want to use Dunn's test https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dunn.test/dunn.test.pdf (I'm assuming that the test images are independent).

Comment: @ping Thanks for the comment - I am not sure it should it matter that I have Dice vs another metric for using the Kruskal-Wallis vs ANOVA? Should I do a test to check normal distribution first?

Comment: Not sure if I understood. Do you want to compare the Dice with another performance metric? I don’t expect Dice to be normally distributed. This strongly depends on the methods you compare.

Comment: @ping, Sorry I am not familiar with the kruskal-wallis test - is there such a thing as a 'repeated' or 'paired-point' kruskal-wallist test?

Comment: if you have repeated measures you may want to use a mixed effect GLM with Beta family (if the scores are defined within (0,1)). Kruskal Wallis is the equivalent non parametric for ANOVA.

Comment: I ended up going with a Friedman's test, as this seems to be the best suited for my data